# What’s the best way to make adaptable tkinter button lists in python?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, calculator

I’m trying to make a calculator app that stores memorized numbers or equations into a list of strings. I’m also trying to create a secondary window that displays a delete button and a label for each memory entry. I’m using a button list and label list for those, and i’m trying to match the indexes of all 3 lists.

When the delete button is pressed, i want to .pop the same index on all three lists and .destroy() the button that was pressed and it’s corresponding label. An example of this function is in the windows 10 calculator app. However, I am aware that if I pop an index, the index after it becomes that index, so you can't just assign each button a fixed index. So I guess the main question is, how can I get the current index of a specific button and use that to determine which string and label to delete in the other 2 lists? I tried using self in memDeleteButtons.index(self), but for some reason it doesn't' resolve to anything.

Below is the code that I'm working on:

```
def memDestroyer(index):
    
    if memBank.__len__() and memDeleteButtons.__len__() and memLabels.__len__() > 0:   
            memLabels[index].destroy()
            memDeleteButtons[index].destroy()

            memLabels.pop(index)
            memBank.pop(index)
            memDeleteButtons.pop(index)                   
    else:
        return    

def memMenu():
    print(memBank)
    global root1
    root1 = Tk()
    root1.title("Saved Equations")
    root1.geometry("300x600")
        
    index = 0
    for i  in memBank:
        print("loop began")  
        if i == "":
            memBank.pop(memBank.index(i)) 
            continue
        elif index >= memBank.__len__():
            break
        else:
            memLabels.append(Label(root1, text=i))
            memLabels[-1].pack()
            memDeleteButtons.append(Button(root1, text="x"))
            memDeleteButtons[-1].config(command=lambda:memDestroyer(memDeleteButtons.index(self)))
            memDeleteButtons[-1].pack() 
        
        index += 1
        print("loop ended")
            
    root1.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could store a list of tuples with the button, the label and the string.

Comment: Thank you so much! So for the buttons, it would be a list of tuples, each tuple containing the button and the button's object id in string form. Would using the syntax memDeleteButtons.index((button, objectID)) be correct for checking where the object id is? I'll do a test on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've figured out how to make the buttons adaptable. I needed to do two things:

1. I needed to reassign indexes to the command attribute on the buttons after popping an index. So I first created a for loop that cycled through the button list and reassigned indexes to their command attributes from 0 onward. This ensured that all buttons would always have an updated command attribute, as before they were always trying to reference an index that would no longer be theirs if an index before them was popped.
2. I needed to write an argument in lambda in the command attribute of each button. The command is lambda c=i: memDestroyer(c). This was because i will always be equal to the last index of the list after the loop concludes, so you can see how that would be a problem. However, by using c = 1, c is not i, it's saving the value that i was once equal to in a specific iteration, so it allows each button to have it's own index assignment.

Here is the code now:

```
def memDestroyer(index):

if memBank.__len__() and memDeleteButtons.__len__() and memLabels.__len__() > 0:   
        print(f"index is {index}")
        memLabels[index].destroy()
        memDeleteButtons[index][0].destroy()
        memLabels.pop(index)
        memBank.pop(index)
        memDeleteButtons.pop(index)
        
        step = 0
        for i in memDeleteButtons:
            print(f"Pointer index is {step}")
            i[0].config(command=lambda c = step: memDestroyer(c))
            step += 1
            
    
else:
    return
    
def memMenu():
    print(memBank)
    global root1
    root1 = Tk()
    root1.title("Saved Equations")
    root1.geometry("300x600")
    
    
    index = 0
    row_index = 1
    for i, v  in enumerate(memBank):
        print("loop began")  
        if v == "":
            memBank.pop(i) 
            continue
        elif i >= memBank.__len__():
            break
        
        else:
            
            
            global button
            
            if memDeleteButtons.__len__() - 1 and memLabels.__len__() - 1 >= i:
                memDeleteButtons.pop(i)
                memLabels.pop(i)
            memLabels.insert(i, Label(root1, text=v))
            memLabels[i].grid(row=row_index, column=2)
            memDeleteButtons.insert(i, [Button(root1, text="x", command=lambda c = i:memDestroyer(i))])
            memDeleteButtons[i][0].grid(row=row_index, column=1) 
           
            # import logging
            # open("Calculator.txt")
           
        index += 1
        row_index += 1
        print(i)
    root1.mainloop()
    return
```